# How is perspective compensated when analyzing the rotation of distant galaxies?

Tags: cosmology, astrophysics, astronomy, galaxies

I can't find any information about that, but I always wondered:

When analyzing a distant galaxy, how is the perspective taken in account when analyzing both its movement and the apparent density distribution of stars on the galaxy?

If a galaxy is tilted, the difference between the edges can be easily more than 10 kly along our line of sight. Meaning we're seeing each of its stars in a significantly different time.

Even if it's perpendicular to our line of sight there are still many light-years of difference between the closest and farthest stars along its thickness.

How is that compensated?

Or is there some argument not to compensate that?

Comment: A related question on our sister site: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43739/16685

Answer (score 1):

One way this effect is taken into account is if the image of the galaxy is large enough to allow independent redshifts to be determined for that portion of the galaxy approaching us and the opposite side of it which is moving away from us. Trigonometry then lets us solve for the actual rotation rate of the galaxy as a function of radius from the center, for example.